# Android Calendar Event - key to identify an event

Tags: android, calendar

I've a question regarding Android's Calendar event.

What key can I use to identify an event If it is sync-ed into 2 different phones from the same calendar (Google calendar for example..)?

I'm building an application for my project, so far it can create,update,delete a calendar event generated by the application, however, the method I use to identify it is by

searching for a keyword in the description with the start and end time. I figured this is not the perfect solution as problem may arise if people change the description content.

Any hint or tips will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You are using the calendar api? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

> I've a question regarding Android's Calendar event.

Android does not have a "Calendar event". Android, the operating system, does not have a standardized concept of a "calendar".

There are several calendar applications available for Android. Perhaps you are thinking of the Calendar application from the Android open source project. However, this application has no documented and supported APIs. If you wish to work with events pertaining to this application, please use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

If you wish to work with events from some other calendar application for Android, contact them to see if they offer an API.

Comment: @ Mayra, I learnt to add new events into calendars via http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276 . Thus, I'm wondering if any other people faces the same problem as me. It is easy to add events, but it is not easy to keep track of the event added is what I think. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, i am having the same kind of question in mind, is there any unique id available for same events available on two different devices, as of now, i am following [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) . Is there any way to go about this. Hoping for better response thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for (some version of) Calendar.java can be found http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/provider/Calendar.java

Perhaps you're looking for "event_id" or "_sync_id". I'm no expert but looking at the source might help you find what you're looking for.

But as everyone always says: Use private APIs at your (and your users') own risk.